# Alignment issue in the taginfo page

Tags: bug, tags, design

There is an alignment issue in the Tag info page, the vote counts and post text are not aligned correctly.

For example in the [winter-bash](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/winter-bash/hot) hot/new questions page, we can see the alignment issue.

Screenshot for reference:

[image: Tag info]